# How to limit the number of result within Magento?

Tags: php, magento, pagination

I've a recent products action in my Catalog/Product controllers.

I retrieve **all** the product sorted by entity id. Works great ok.

The problem is I just want to show 20 products in 4 pages.

I tried to extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and override `_getProductCollection()` and I did something like this:

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc')
                ->addStoreFilter();
```

And the important part:

```
$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->limit($this->getProductsLimit());
```

If I 'dump' the returned Object I've something like this:

["limitcount"] => int(5)
 ["limitoffset"] => int(0)

So it looks to be overriden by the paginator.

Do you know a way to limit properly the number of result?

For both optimization and presentation I actually don't want to retrieve all the products collection.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

That should work...

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc')
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->setPage($pageNum, $pageSize);

// only retrieve 10 products
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc')
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->setPage(0, 10);
```

Comment: My problem is I **need** the pagination, but on a limited range of products. 20 products in 4 pages of 5 products. With your solution, I'll limit my product to one page of 10 products, but won't be able to use pagination. I actually need to limit the collection, not the result.

Comment: hmm not sure were you are having any problems, but ```->setPage($page /*0-3*/, 5 /* 5 products per page*/);
``` should work with no problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->setPageSize(20)
->setCurPage(1);`

Comment: The answer is correct. This will limit 0,20. If u set current page 2 the it will be 21,40.

Comment: Thanks, Please vote my answer so that other can get benefited.

Answer (score 1):

Another, equally valid, way is with:

```
$this->_productCollection->setPageSize($this->getProductsLimit());
```

Answer (score 0):

Select 20 products:-

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc')
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->setPageSize(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after obtaining the collection:

`$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->limit( 20 );`