# How can I override and use easily Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract?

Tags: php, collections, magento, model, overriding

In order to find a solution for [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272323/how-to-limit-the-number-of-result-within-magento) I'd like to override `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` I know I can copy it from `core/` to `local/` but that'll break further updates.

So I'd like to extend it instead.

If I do how to do it?

I'm totally new to extension with Magento, and I'm not totally sure I can this without breaking existing code.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry you can't overwrite an abstract class as the class that use them are linked to them directly
e.g.

My_Collection extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract

you can only overwrite classes that get initialised using Mage::getResourceModel() or Mage::getModel() ,...

For your problem you don't need to do so I think...

Comment: +1 for "you don't need to do so". The previous question wasn't hard and messing with a widely used parent class will only break other things you can't anticipate.